# How do I run as bash script from a WebApp?

Tags: bash, scripts, shutdown, webapps, kiosk

I currently am developing a custom Ubuntu dist. that runs a dedicated Kiosk app upon boot. I would like an easy method to shutdown from inside the Kiosk app, but I am currently at a standstill at what I can do to run a bash script from the app itself. The Kiosk app (custom, and proprietary) that I am using, is a WebApp. I know what the bash script is suppose to contain to shut down the system, but I can't figure out how to actually execute the script from the Kiosk WebApp. Any help?

Comment: its hard to say explicitly without more detail. What is your web app programed in? anyhow, make a system call to the shutdown function. you can do this with cgi script, or a php script or... many things

Comment: If the webapp is written in PHP you can use [`shell_exec`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) to run any command like `shutdown --poweroff`or a script (read about the security risks). Other languages have their equivalent. If you can't change the kiosk source code seems impossible.